# Generate function by its arguments and internal call arguments on a HAXE

Tags: macros, haxe

Trying to generate the functions to fill lthe class with api methods.

not sure how to determine function argument parameters from strings and internal call valuable arguments

```
            var todo:haxe.macro.Function = {args: arguments};
            
            todo.expr = macro {
                trace($v{funcname});
                
                return api_call($v{funcname});  
            };
            
            
            todo.ret = macro : Dynamic;

            var f:Field = {
                name: funcname.replaceAll('.', '_'),
                pos: Context.currentPos(),
                kind: FFun(todo),
                access: [APublic], // optional
                doc: null, // optional
                meta: [], // optional
            }

            fields.push(f);
```

trying to create the macro type function and add fields but got some errors.

Comment: What errors? And what are the `arguments` here?

Comment: need easy way to create lexical constructions.